# Create a numeric string using three variables

Tags: python

I need to create script to print numeric string using three variables x y z
The user enters range

```
s=input("Enter S") #s=1

e=input("Enter E") #e=10
```

and the script write `print (x, y, z)`

```
1, 2, 3

4, 5, 6

7, 8, 9
```

another example

```
s=input("Enter S") #s=10

e=input("Enter E") #e=19
```

the script print `print (x, y, z)`

```
10, 11, 12

13, 14, 15

16, 17, 18
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? and what about the three variables `(x,y,z)`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html

Comment: Yes i tried to create it but the problem is the numbers repeated and i had choose three variables randomly for example

Comment: @AbdulraheemKhaled: If you show us what you tried, we can probably explain what you got wrong, and how to fix it. (In fact, I have a guess without even seeing it: you set `x`, `y`, and `z` all to the same list, instead of to three separate lists. But you'll get a lot better than a wild guess if you show us your code.) That way, you'll get working code, and an understanding of how to do it yourself next time, instead of just code that does something that may or may not be what you wanted and that you probably don't understand well enough to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you i was searching about something like that

```
s=input('Enter S')
e=input('Enter E')
A=[]
for x in range (s,e):
 A.append(x)
 if len(A)==3:
  print(A[0],A[1],A[2])
  del A[0:3]
```

Sorry i was not helpful in describe what i want

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what `x`, `y` and `z` are for, but this might be what you're looking for:

```
>>> s = 10
>>> e = 19
>>> for i in xrange(s, e):
...     print i,
...     if (i - s) % 3 == 2:
...         print
... 
10 11 12
13 14 15
16 17 18
```

In `Python3`, the preceding code fails, because:

1. The `xrange`  function was renamed [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#range).
2. The [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#print) statement was changed into a function.

Therefore, this is the corrected version of the code:

```
>>> for i in range(s, e):
...     print(i, end=' ')
...     if (i - s) % 3 == 2:
...         print('')
... 
10 11 12 
13 14 15 
16 17 18
```

Comment: the OP I imagine is using python 3